# Makefile - prereq-patterns % in $(wildcard)

Tags: makefile

I want to add rules of `.cc` files to a static mode rule. And I try to use `$(wildcard )` to enable the prereq-pattern which exists in folder in order to avoid a `No rule to make target ...` error. But `%` in `$(wildcard )` isn't transformed to the file basename. `$(wildcard %.cpp)` and `$(wildcard %.cc)` turn to be nothing.

I want to know how to solve this and make `.cc`, `.cpp` in one static mode rule.

```
# before
# CXX_SOURCE_FILE = $(wildcard *.cpp)

CXX_SOURCE_FILE = $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard *.cc)

C++ = g++

CXX_FLAGS = -g -Wall

c++ : $(basename $(CXX_SOURCE_FILE))

# before
# $(basename $(CXX_SOURCE_FILE)) : % : %.cpp
#   $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)

$(basename $(CXX_SOURCE_FILE)) : % : $(wildcard %.cpp) $(wildcard %.cc)
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `wildcard` like this because it will be evaluated during the parsing, before static pattern rules are considered. Unless you have source files that are literally `%.cpp` or `%.cc` your prerequisite list will be empty when the time comes to consider the rules.

A simple solution consists in separating your two sets of source files (`CPP_SOURCE_FILE` and `CC_SOURCE_FILE`) and use two different static pattern rules:

```
CPP_SOURCE_FILE = $(wildcard *.cpp)
CC_SOURCE_FILE = $(wildcard *.cc)

$(basename $(CPP_SOURCE_FILE)): %: %.cpp
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)

$(basename $(CC_SOURCE_FILE)): %: %.cc
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)
```

There are other solutions but they are more complicated. If you use GNU make you can either use the [`foreach-eval-call` construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) or the [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion).

Example with `foreach-eval-call`:

```
# $1: executable
define MY_rule
$1: $$(wildcard $1.cpp) $$(wildcard $1.cc)
    $$(C++) $$< -o $$@ $$(CXX_FLAGS)
endef
$(foreach e,$(basename $(CXX_SOURCE_FILE)),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$e)))
```

For executable `foo` this will call `MY_rule` with parameter `foo`, pass the result to `eval` that will expand it and instantiate it as a new rule. `$(call MY_rule,foo)` expands as:

```
foo: $$(wildcard foo.cpp) $$(wildcard foo.cc)
    $$(C++) $$< -o $$@ $$(CXX_FLAGS)
```

`eval` expands it as:

```
foo: $(wildcard foo.cpp) $(wildcard foo.cc)
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)
```

This is exactly what you wanted for this executable. Note the need of `$$` to escape the first expansion by `eval`.

Example with secondary expansion:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(basename $(CXX_SOURCE_FILE)): $$(wildcard $$@.cpp) $$(wildcard $$@.cc)
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)
```

After the first expansion, during the parsing of the Makefile, this becomes:

```
foo bar baz: $(wildcard $@.cpp) $(wildcard $@.cc)
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)
```

Note that if you were trying to use this rule in your Makefile, instead of your static pattern rule, this would not work for the very same reason: when the Makefile is parsed and the prerequisites are expanded the automatic variables are not yet set. So, unless you have files named `.cpp` or `.cc` your liste of prerequisites would also be empty.

But every rule after `.SECONDEXPANSION:` has its prerequisites expanded a second time. And the second time, different from the first, the automatic variables are set, including `$@`. The final result is equivalent to the 3 following rules:

```
foo: $(wildcard foo.cpp) $(wildcard foo.cc)
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)

bar: $(wildcard bar.cpp) $(wildcard bar.cc)
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)

baz: $(wildcard baz.cpp) $(wildcard baz.cc)
    $(C++) $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)
```

From the GNU make manual:

> the true power of this feature only becomes apparent when you discover that secondary expansions always take place within the scope of the automatic variables for that target. This means that you can use variables such as $@, $*, etc. during the second expansion and they will have their expected values, just as in the recipe. All you have to do is defer the expansion by escaping the $.

Note: here again the `$$` are essential to escape the first expansion.

Comment: Personally I agree with the "Final note" here.  Just write two rules.  It's much, much simpler and you don't need to learn all about these advanced make features.

Comment: OK, so let's put the final note first...